# creating multiple tabs in the xterm session of cygwin

Tags: windows, linux, terminal

I am new to cygwin, since I usually use Linux. I had a quick question regarding it. From the xterm window of cywin, how do I create multiple terminal tabs, so that I can have multiple ssh (with X11 forwarding) sessions from the same window?
I tried googling this, but could not find any useful link for this problem.... I am sure there is some way to do this, just can't figure it out.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already open to starting up X11, check out mrxvt.  It does multiple tabs, and last I checked, it built smoothly under Cygwin.

There's also Terminator, which is a java terminal emulator...  ISTR it doesn't require X11.